# MsTest unable to copy test data files to build server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, continuous-integration, mstest, specflow

I am trying to implement automated unit testing with each build using TFS.

Problem statement :

I have created few xml files which stores test data and set to copy always. When run locally files are picked up from bin folder. When I schedule a build, build process looks for files in **out** folder under **TestResults** on Build Server. Out folder contains ddls but not the xml files. Hence unable to find files and results into build failure partially.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify additional files to deploy in your test settings file:

[image]

More details here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the DeploymentItem Attribute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx